# Right align a string formula in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, formula

I've got a crystal reports formula that displays a string based on an input

Simplified:

```
if (a=1) then
    "Abc"
else
    "Abcdefghijkl"
```

The problem is that I want this field right aligned. In the "Format Editor" I have set the "Horizontal Alignment" to be "Right", but it hasn't changed the formatting when I run the report.

Any idea's on to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I pulled up a .rpt of my own and mucked around with it.  Does the output have alot of trailing whitespace, i.e. `Abc________`?  If so, a simple trim() could fix it.

*where _ is a whitespace. StackOverflow won't let me display whitespaces as white spaces*